# How to run python script which require sudoer

Tags: php, python, apache

I have a a requirement to stop/start some service using sudo service  stop/start using python script. The script will be called by a webpage php code on server side running apache webserver.
One way I know is to give www-data sudoer permission to run the specific python script. 
Is there other way without giving www-data specific permission. Example will cgi or mod_python work in this case. If yes what is the best implementation to all python script execution in LAMP server. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no security issue with giving www-data the sudo right for a single restart command without any wildcards.

If you want to avoid using sudo at all, you can create a temporary file with php, and poll for this file from a shell script executed by root regularly.

But this may be more error prown, and leads to the same result.

Comment: i added www-data to sudoer list /etc/sudoers
www-data ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /folder/path/myscript.py
however www-data still ask for password. I did a test by giving www-data full rights www-data ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL then the script runs fine. I checked www-data as owner of the myscript.py file.

Comment: The python script should run as www-data, and call sudo service stop.

Comment: www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/service whatever stop

Comment: thanks visit1985. This solved my question. The service I was trying to stop was in /usr/sbin/service. Your answer and some more digging solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a python thread that listens to a stop/start request, and then this thread will stop/start the service. The thread should run as sudo, but it listens to tcp. The web server can send requests w/o any special permissions (SocketServer is a very simple out-of-the-box python tcp server).

You may want to add some security, e.g. hashing the request to this server with a secret, so only allowed services will be able to request the start/stop of the service, and apply iptables rules (requests from localhost where the web server is)